Setting Grid Color of Radar Chart in Chart.js
I have a radar chart with 360 labels and I would like to hide the grid lines emanating from the center of the chart or color them to match the canvas. Changing the r axis grid properties doesn't affect these grid lines. I've tried adjusting values for x, y and z but that doesn't seem to work. I'm open to using other versions of the packages below if necessary.

Is it possible to hide these grid lines -- perhaps with a Chart.defaults.elements.* statement?
package.json
"chart.js": "^4.4.1",
"chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^3.0.0",
"chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^3.0.1",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",

EDIT: for completeness, here are the options for the chart:
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
      intersect: false,
      mode: 'index',
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
      borderColor: '#666666',
      borderWidth: 1,
      titleAlign: 'center',
      callbacks:{
        label: context => {
          let label = context.dataset.label || ''
          return `${label}: ${context.parsed.r} mph`
        },
        labelColor: function(context) {
          let label = context.dataset.label || ''
          if (label === 'Gust') {
            return {
              borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
              borderWidth: 3,
              borderDash: [2, 2],
              borderRadius: 2,
            }
          } else {
            return {
              borderColor: 'rgb(0,200,255, 1)',
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,200,255, 1)',
              borderWidth: 3,
              borderRadius: 2,
            }
          }
        },
      }
    },
  },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  animation: {
    duration: this.animation,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuart'
  },
  scales: {
    r: {
      grid: {
        color: "#333333",
        display: true,
        borderDash: [1, 2],
        circular: true,
      },
      ticks: {
        backdropColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)", // transparent
        color: "#888888",
        stepSize: this.stepSizeR(),
      },
    },
  }
},



Found it. This may not be the only way to achieve this, but it does work:
Chart.defaults.borderColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
Chart.defaults.borderColor = '#fff'

